# how to draw a custom data flow in elastic kibana based on logs data

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I want to create some kibana visualization that I am not sure is possible...

it goes like this :
so all my documents have a property called **sessionId** (the purpose is to group some documents based on the sessionId)

i want to create a visualization that will get a sessionId from a user input

-> fetch all matching documents
-> For each document draw a square with some text inside the square

can I do this?